# Execution time exceeded run time cap on Vertica query execution from Python

Tags: python, runtime, vertica, vertica-python

I have a SQL query that runs on Vertica DB and completes after ~25 minutes (using DataGrip).

However, when executing the query from Python, using **vertica_python** package, it fails after 20 minutes due to run time cap, with the following error message:

`vertica_python.errors.QueryCanceled: Severity: ERROR, Message: Execution time exceeded run time cap of 00:20, Sqlstate: 57014`

Obviously, the run time cap is enabled only when the query runs from Python, because it succeeds when it runs from DataGrip after more than 20 minutes.

Below is a simple code example:

```
import pandas as pd
from vertica_python import connect

query = "SELECT * FROM ..."
vertica_connection_info = {"host": hst, "port": prt, "user": usr, "password": pwd}
connection = connect(**vertica_connection_info)
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
result = cur.fetchall()
columns = [d.name for d in cur.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=columns)
```

I'd like to change the RUNTIMECAP from 20m to 30m but I couldn't find where it's configured.

Comment: Doesn't the connect method has `read_timeout` variable? You can modify that in your `connect` call.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work @minatverma

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you are able to fire a simple original command with your Python client:

Here, I do it with my plain vanilla sql client: `vsql`. I ask Vertica which resource pool I'm assigned to, and I ask Vertica again what are the settings of the resource pool I'm assigned to:

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql
Welcome to vsql, the Vertica Analytic Database interactive terminal.

Type:  \h or \? for help with vsql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

sbx=> show resource pool;
     name      | setting 
---------------+---------
 resource_pool | general
sbx=> \pset null '(null)'
Null display is "(null)".
sbx=> select * from resource_pools where name='general';
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------+------------------
pool_id                  | 45035996273704996
name                     | general
subcluster_oid           | 0
subcluster_name          | (null)
is_internal              | t
memorysize               | 
maxmemorysize            | Special: 95%
maxquerymemorysize       | 
executionparallelism     | AUTO
priority                 | 0
runtimepriority          | MEDIUM
runtimeprioritythreshold | 2
queuetimeout             | 00:05
plannedconcurrency       | AUTO
maxconcurrency           | (null)
runtimecap               | (null)
singleinitiator          | f
cpuaffinityset           | (null)
cpuaffinitymode          | ANY
cascadeto                | (null)
cascadetosubclusterpool  | (null)

sbx=>
```

So I'm currently running with resource pool `general` - whose run time cap is set to NULL - so , never.

You will be assigned to a resource pool different than `general`, and your `SELECT * FROM resource_pools WHERE name='<<your resource pool_s name>>'` will return `00:20` for `runtimecap`. You will have to ask your database administrator - or whoever else is privileged to change resource pools to change that runtime cap value - or create a different resource pool for you and assign you to it by default.